# JavaScript array search to return index position for 2 element search

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to search a JSON set for 2 elements of an array. If a match is found for these 2 elements, I need the index of this position. And once I have this index, I can use this to access a different property in this same array position.

Below is sample of what I have. If you look at line 22, I am hard-coding the array position to 1. This is the value I dynamically need depending on what I pass into my getModelID() function.

http://codepen.io/bdang/pen/pJvmox/?editors=101

```
function getModelID(extClr, intClr) {

    var colorLockDatesAr = lockDates.Models[0].Colors,
        colorLockDatesCount = colorLockDatesAr.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < colorLockDatesCount; i++) {      

        if(colorLockDatesAr[i].ExtColorCd == extClr && colorLockDatesAr[i].IntColorCd == intClr) {          

            $('#modelID').html(colorLockDatesAr[1].ModelID);

        }   
    }   
}

getModelID('BK', 'BK'); // should return Model 1
getModelID('BK', 'WH'); // should return Model 2
getModelID('WH', 'BK'); // should return Model 3
```

I have looked through various forums and many issues I've found are related issues but none specific to what I need. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `i`

```
$('#modelID').html(colorLockDatesAr[i].ModelID);
```

http://codepen.io/miguelmota/pen/xGbNVG